# Reverse an array in place in JavaScript using Array.prototype.pop(), the return value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a JavaScript function `reverseArrayInPlace(origin)` that reverse an array in place. That is,

```
let orignalArray = [1, 2, 3];

reverseArrayInPlace(orignalArray);

console.log(orignalArray); // [3, 2, 1]
```

I know there is a trick that uses the **Array.pop()** method, by pushing the popped value to an empty result array, then return that result array. But it turns out the original array will become empty.

In order to modify the original array, I've tried it to assign the value of result reversed array to the original array (the argument), then return the original array. Using below three approaches:

`origin = result;`

`origin = [...result];`

`origin.push(...result);`

And here comes my question, the first or second does not work as I expected, but the third works fine.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace1(origin) {
    let result = [];
    while (origin.length > 0) {
        result.push(origin.pop());
    }
    origin = result; // not work
    return origin;
}

function reverseArrayInPlace2(origin) {
    let result = [];
    while (origin.length > 0) {
        result.push(origin.pop());
    }
    origin = [...result]; // not work
    return origin;
}

function reverseArrayInPlace3(origin) {
    let result = [];
    while (origin.length > 0) {
        result.push(origin.pop());
    }
    origin.push(...result); // it works
    return origin;
}

let orignalArray1 = [1, 2, 3];
let orignalArray2 = [1, 2, 3];
let orignalArray3 = [1, 2, 3];

reverseArrayInPlace1(orignalArray1); // [3, 2, 1]
reverseArrayInPlace2(orignalArray2); // [3, 2, 1]
reverseArrayInPlace3(orignalArray3); // [3, 2, 1]

console.log(orignalArray1); // []
console.log(orignalArray2); // []
console.log(orignalArray3); // [3, 2, 1]
```

The return value of above functions is Ok, but the console.log result of the first and second is not what I want.

Can some one explain why the original array's value not changed after function return when I assign the result array to it directly using `=`? And why it changes as expected when using `push()`?

Comment: `origin` is a local variable to the function containing a reference to the original array.

Comment: When you pass in a parameter of `origin` that contains a reference to the original array. If you re-assign the variable, that doesn't change the original object, just sets it to point to a new one.

Comment: @VLAZ But why in `console.log(originalArray)` the original still points to the `[]`, not the new one?

Comment: Because you've only changed `origin`, not `originalArray`. Again, these start off as **references** to the same object, when you reassign one, you are only changing what one of these points to. The original object stays intact as does anything that still points to it.